# Multiplying numbers with number 12 on Logisim

Tags: logisim

I need a bit help/tips about solving my exercises.
So I got the excerise as follow: Im gonna multiply all 4-bit numbers (0-15) with the decimal number 12.
Now, 12 is 1100.

Input is going to be 4 bit, and output should give us 8 bit, because 12*15 is the highest output number.

Now the exercise requires us that if we eg. need to use adder, we have got to implement the adder by basic gates.

As now I've made a table on my notebook with all inputs and outputs such that:
If innput is 0000, then output is 00000000 etc..

So to multiply binary numbers it should be eg.:

$$1100 :(m_0=1,m_1=1,m_2=0,m_3=0)$$

and we use the number two in this case:
$$ 0010: (n_0=0,n_1=0,n_2=1,n_3=0)$$

So we got to use AND-gate for each 'n' and 'm' combination, which gives us 8  AND-gates.

But on that part im stuck, and I really dont know if im doing the right steps...

Tips are highly appreciated.

Comment: Everything after "*then output is 00000000 etc..*" makes me go "aha... what?". - I believe the exercise wants you to *understand* what a multiplication *actually* is. So can you please elaborate (in high level, like with words) how you are going to solve this? Then we can see if *that* thinking is correct.

Comment: Tip: start with finding out how to multiply with 2, 4, 8, 16. Then think about 12.

Comment: @Oldfart Yeah, thats nearly like decimal numbers. So if we multiply a number with 0010 then we just got to add a bit (0) in the end.
Same with 0100 (two zeros at the end)

Comment: @MZ97 And if we multiply a number by 1100... then it's simply shifting your 4 bit number twice to the left... and then..............

Comment: @HarrySvensson hmm.. 1111x1100= 10110100?  Im not sure how it is shifting..?

Comment: Think about 1111x1100= 10110100 in a more step by step way....

Comment: @Tyler 1111x0100x0011...?

Comment: If you had 5 x 12 = 60; you could also write it as 5 x ( 10 + 2 ) or (5 X 10) + (5 x 2).

Comment: @MZ97 This will be my last comment. I will continue from my earlier comment. - .... call it "*a*", shift your 4 bit number again (a total of 3) to the left, call this "*b*". Then sum *a* and *b* together to form *c*. This *c* is the same as 4 bit register multiplied by 12. - If you don't understand what I just said, then that's fine. - It just means that you need to read up some more on multiplication.  Good luck.

Comment: You may wish to recall long multiplication from high school, then consider how the idea would apply to binary numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Reading your question led me initially to a high level solution.

Your text mentions multiplication and addition. So, I thought about how to accomplish this task and what came to mind was to perform two multiplications and an addition.

$$Input(b) * 1100 = (Input(b) * 1000) + (Input(b) * 0100)$$

And we know that binary multiplication by powers of 2 is just an equivalent number of bit shifts to the left.

So in Logisim I came up with the following high level implementation. The registers are there just so it can easily be seen what the values are.

[image: Image 1]

Since your question also stated that everything should be implemented on a gate level, I broke the above image into gate level equivalent. The shift registers are not needed as you can just route the signals accordingly and implement a few 1 bit adders with carry.

Output Bits 0 and 1 will always be zero.

Output Bit 2 will always be Input bit 0. There is no Carry in.

Output Bits 3 thru 6 will be the results of the additions.

Output Bit 7 will be the carry out of the last addition.

[image]

There are several gates that can be eliminated, however for understanding I feel it better to keep the gates there to preserve the look of the adders for the visualization of whats happening.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming \$C_i\$ represents the bits in the output and that \$A_i\$ represents the bits taken from the input (\$B_i\$ being the multiplier bits), you already know:

1. \$C_0=C_1=0\$ (Obvious by simple inspection of the binary value of your multiplier, which has \$B_0=B_1=0\$.)
2. \$C_2=A_0\$ (After accounting for #1 above, you are left with multiplying by 3. And odd numbers times 3 produce odd results. And even numbers times 3 produce even results.)
3. \$C_3=A_0 \:\operatorname{xor}\:A_1\$ (If you lay out a table of values, only 16 results to worry about so this can easily be done by hand, you will readily notice this fact by a simple inspection. But you can also realize this from the fact that you are really just multiplying by 3, once you take into account note #1 above, and that this means \$A_0\$ is effectively added to \$A_1\$ and that discounting any carries this is a simple XOR operation.)

So that's half of your output, already. You've only four more bits to worry about. (Admittedly, harder ones.)

These remaining bits are far more easily laid out now in the four required 4-in (2 across, 2 down) K-maps for analyzing the output bits independently. This really isn't a lot of work to perform by hand. And had you bothered to write out the other four k-maps (for the bits I just mentioned above in #1, #2, and #3 above) you would have even more easily seen the truth of the above items I've already handed you.

I think it's time you sit down with a few K-maps. It's only four of them. And if you want to be efficient with your gates, you can also cross-inspect your individual solutions to see if there are some common factors to take advantage of.

If you aren't familiar with K-maps, this is the time to go read up on them. At this level of use, they really are pretty easy to work through.

---

Here's my attempt to get you started. (You may already know about K-maps, but there are others who may read this and need a boost I'd like to provide them.)

You should be able to produce the above maps almost as fast as your hand can write. Just lay out your 16 binary input values for \$A\$, sorted in their binary sequence order. Next to each, lay out columns for each bit in the output (eight total, but the least significant two are too trivial to care about so ignore the trivial \$C_0\$ and \$C_1\$.) This results in 16 rows and 6 columns of results.

$$\begin{smallmatrix}
\begin{array}{cccc|ccccccc}
A_3&A_2&A_1&A_0&C_7&C_6&C_5&C_4&C_3&C_2\\
\hline
0&0&0&0& 0&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&1& 0&0&0&0&1&1\\
0&0&1&0& 0&0&0&1&1&0\\
0&0&1&1& 0&0&1&0&0&1\\
0&1&0&0& 0&0&1&1&0&0\\
0&1&0&1& 0&0&1&1&1&1\\
0&1&1&0& 0&1&0&0&1&0\\
0&1&1&1& 0&1&0&1&0&1\\
1&0&0&0& 0&1&1&0&0&0\\
1&0&0&1& 0&1&1&0&1&1\\
1&0&1&0& 0&1&1&1&1&0\\
1&0&1&1& 1&0&0&0&0&1\\
1&1&0&0& 1&0&0&1&0&0\\
1&1&0&1& 1&0&0&1&1&1\\
1&1&1&0& 1&0&1&0&1&0\\
1&1&1&1& 1&0&1&1&0&1
\end{array}
\end{smallmatrix}$$

Now, re-order your 16 rows by swapping pairs of adjacent rows with \$A_1=1\$. Then, once that is done, swap the last group of four rows with the prior group of four rows (where \$A_3=1\$):

$$\begin{smallmatrix}
\begin{array}{cccc|ccccccc}
A_3&A_2&A_1&A_0&C_7&C_6&C_5&C_4&C_3&C_2\\
\hline
0&0&0&0& 0&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&1& 0&0&0&0&1&1\\
0&0&1&1& 0&0&1&0&0&1\\
0&0&1&0& 0&0&0&1&1&0\\
0&1&0&0& 0&0&1&1&0&0\\
0&1&0&1& 0&0&1&1&1&1\\
0&1&1&1& 0&1&0&1&0&1\\
0&1&1&0& 0&1&0&0&1&0\\
1&1&0&0& 1&0&0&1&0&0\\
1&1&0&1& 1&0&0&1&1&1\\
1&1&1&1& 1&0&1&1&0&1\\
1&1&1&0& 1&0&1&0&1&0\\
1&0&0&0& 0&1&1&0&0&0\\
1&0&0&1& 0&1&1&0&1&1\\
1&0&1&1& 1&0&0&0&0&1\\
1&0&1&0& 0&1&1&1&1&0\\
\end{array}
\end{smallmatrix}$$

You can now build one K-map for each result column, one at a time. All you do is read off the first four values as the first row of your K-map; then next four as the next row; and so on.
, your K-maps look like:

$$
\begin{array}{rl}
\begin{smallmatrix}\begin{array}{r|cccc}
C_7&\overline{A_1}\:\overline{A_0}&\overline{A_1}\: A_0&A_1 \:A_0&A_1 \:\overline{A_0}\\
\hline
\overline{A_3}\:\overline{A_2}&0&0&0&0\\
\overline{A_3}\:A_2&0&0&0&0\\
A_3\: A_2&1&1&1&1\\
A_3\:\overline{A_2}&0&0&1&0
\end{array}\end{smallmatrix}
&
\begin{smallmatrix}\begin{array}{r|cccc}
C_6&\overline{A_1}\:\overline{A_0}&\overline{A_1}\: A_0&A_1\: A_0&A_1 \:\overline{A_0}\\
\hline
\overline{A_3}\:\overline{A_2}&0&0&0&0\\
\overline{A_3}\:A_2&0&0&1&1\\
A_3\: A_2&0&0&0&0\\
A_3\:\overline{A_2}&1&1&0&1
\end{array}\end{smallmatrix}\\\\
\begin{smallmatrix}\begin{array}{r|cccc}
C_5&\overline{A_1}\:\overline{A_0}&\overline{A_1}\: A_0&A_1\: A_0&A_1 \:\overline{A_0}\\
\hline
\overline{A_3\:}\overline{A_2}&0&0&1&0\\
\overline{A_3}\:A_2&1&1&0&0\\
A_3\: A_2&0&0&1&1\\
A_3\:\overline{A_2}&1&1&0&1
\end{array}\end{smallmatrix}
&
\begin{smallmatrix}\begin{array}{r|cccc}
C_4&\overline{A_1}\:\overline{A_0}&\overline{A_1}\: A_0&A_1\: A_0&A_1\: \overline{A_0}\\
\hline
\overline{A_3}\:\overline{A_2}&0&0&0&1\\
\overline{A_3}\:A_2&1&1&1&0\\
A_3\: A_2&1&1&1&0\\
A_3\:\overline{A_2}&0&0&0&1
\end{array}\end{smallmatrix}\\\\
\begin{smallmatrix}\begin{array}{r|cccc}
C_3&\overline{A_1}\:\overline{A_0}&\overline{A_1}\: A_0&A_1\: A_0&A_1\: \overline{A_0}\\
\hline
\overline{A_3}\:\overline{A_2}&0&1&0&1\\
\overline{A_3}\:A_2&0&1&0&1\\
A_3\: A_2&0&1&0&1\\
A_3\:\overline{A_2}&0&1&0&1
\end{array}\end{smallmatrix}
&
\begin{smallmatrix}\begin{array}{r|cccc}
C_2&\overline{A_1}\:\overline{A_0}&\overline{A_1}\: A_0&A_1\: A_0&A_1\: \overline{A_0}\\
\hline
\overline{A_3}\:\overline{A_2}&0&1&1&0\\
\overline{A_3}\:A_2&0&1&1&0\\
A_3\: A_2&0&1&1&0\\
A_3\:\overline{A_2}&0&1&1&0
\end{array}\end{smallmatrix}
\end{array}
$$
It's that easy.

Once you have all this laid out, all you need to do is follow some of the [simplifying ideas about K-maps](http://www.ee.surrey.ac.uk/Projects/Labview/minimisation/karrules.html) that you can read [here](http://www.ee.surrey.ac.uk/Projects/Labview/minimisation/karrules.html).

This should flow easily, now. I've provided all of the steps and details and lead you to the water itself, too. You should be able to follow a process that will provide you complete success in your project.

Comment: This also works, solving it without any "*actual*" arithmetic units.

Comment: @HarrySvensson Yeah. My first response upon reading "Logisim" was to think, "Well, Logisim includes a multiplier." But then I read that the OP has to use gates. So this motivated my reply.